# How to access return value from coldfusion.ajax.submitform?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

Having real trouble wrapping my head around coldfusion.ajax.submitform. I have the call to my cfc working, data gets saved to my db, however I don't receive (or haven't set-up properly) a way to receive a message that the method call was successful. Here's my code:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="postFeedback" access="remote" returntype="boolean">
  <cfargument name="name" type = "string" required="yes">
      <cfargument name="email" type = "string" required="yes">
      <cfargument name="post" type = "string" required="yes">
      <cfquery name="postFeedback" datasource="myDB">
    Insert into feedback (name, email, post, date)
    Values('#ARGUMENTS.name#','#ARGUMENTS.email#','#ARGUMENTS.post#', #Now()#);
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here's my ajax call:

```
function submitForm() {
   ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('myForm1', 'Feedback.cfc?method=postFeedback', callback, errorHandler);

}

function callback(text)
{
    alert("Callback: " + code + ": " + msg);
}


function errorHandler(code, msg)
{
    alert("Error!!! " + code + ": " + msg);
}
```

I eventually want to understand how to access returned values so that I can use a method like 'getFeedback' and populate fields. I can already do this with cfinvoke but I'm looking to do this via a button click. I need to crawl before I can walk. ;)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=JavaScriptFcns_03.html)

> > **callbackhandler**
> >
> > The JavaScript function to handle a normal response. **The function must take a single argument, that contains the response body.** This method is used only if the form submission is asynchronous.

Compare that to:

> > **errorhandler**
> >
> > The JavaScript function to handle an HTTP error response. **The function must take two arguments: the HTTP status code, and the error message.** This method is used only if the form submission is asynchronous.

You seem to be trying to access the errorhandler arguments with the callbackhandler.

```
function callback(text)
    {
        alert("Callback: " + code + ": " + msg);
    }
```

You might want to try:

```
function callback(text)
    {
        alert("Callback: " + text);
    }
```